# Issue executing Dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamicquery

I have a SQL set of instructions that I want to execute across multiple databases. I currently have the following SQL code:

```
USE Database1

DECLARE @mySourceTable AS [someUserDefinedType];
/*Execute set of operations on Database 1 and @mySourceTable*/

DECLARE @dbList TABLE (DBName nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @dbList (DBName)
VALUES('Database2'),('Database3');

DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(50);

DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DBName FROM @dbList;

OPEN dbCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @dbName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('USE ' + @dbName + N'; 

    DECLARE @content AS [someUserDefinedType];

    INSERT INTO @content (ID)
    SELECT ID FROM '+ @mySourceTable + N';

    EXECUTE dbo.someProcedure @content;'); 

    FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @dbName;
END;

CLOSE dbCursor;
DEALLOCATE dbCursor;
```

Basically I want to do the following: I have several databases that all have the same `[someUserDefinedType]` table type (with the same structure) and a procedure named `dbo.someProcedure` that receives as a parameter a table of said type (the `dbo.someProcedure` is not the same across databases, it is specific to each). I want to go through the list of provided databases (`@dbList`) and execute each stored procedure with data from `@mySourceTable`. I am not sure if the code above is the best approach, it does not work and gives the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@mySourceTable".

This variable is already declared at the beginning of the script. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to pass the data from `@mySourceTable` using a variable and not create another table for it (I really want to avoid that)?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
USE Database1

DECLARE @mySourceTable AS [someUserDefinedType];
/*Execute set of operations on Database 1 and @mySourceTable*/

DECLARE @dbList TABLE (DBName nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @dbList (DBName)
VALUES('Database2'),('Database3');

DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(50);

DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DBName FROM @dbList;

OPEN dbCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @dbName;

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'

    USE ' + @dbName + '; 

    DECLARE @content AS [someUserDefinedType];

    INSERT INTO @content (ID)
    SELECT ID FROM @mySourceTable;

    EXECUTE dbo.someProcedure @content;'; 

    FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @dbName;

    EXEC sp_executesql  @DynamicTSQLStatement, N'@mySourceTable someUserDefinedType readonly', @mySourceTable =  @mySourceTable

END;

CLOSE dbCursor;
DEALLOCATE dbCursor;
```

When you are executing T-SQL statement with `sp_executesql` you can pass parameters.

Comment: I tried this and got the following error: Operand type clash: [someUserDefinedType] is incompatible with [someUserDefinedType]. I am not sure that this is possible. From what I understand, it passes @mySourceTable of type Database1..[@mySourceTable] and is interpreted as Database2..[@mySourceTable]?

Comment: @user2399378 could you try now?

Comment: `someUserDefinedType` is your type name, right? and is this user type defined in the other databases?

Comment: Yes but SQL server does not see them as the same type even if they have exactly the same structure. Since they are created in different databases I cannot substitute one for the other. I believe that is why your code does not work. I think I might have to use a temp table for this instead of table variable.

Comment: I think the problem is here: EXEC sp_executesql  DynamicTSQLStatement, N'mySourceTable someUserDefinedType readonly', mySourceTable =  mySourceTable. It is defining mySourceTable to be of the type Database2..someUserDefinedType and it is receiving mySourceTable of type Database1..someUserDefinedType hence the error

Comment: @user2399378 Yes, you can create outer temporary table and populate it. Then read from it.